# Update a table with the ListBox items in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to update a table using the listbox item. I am having error 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks for your Help

HTML

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="lbSampleID" runat="server" Height="99px" Width="131px">   </asp:ListBox>

<input type="button"  id="btnUpdateConsent" value="Update Consent"     onclick="updateConsent();" class="auto-style142" />
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

         function updateConsent() {

             var SampleID = document.getElementById("lbSampleID").value;
             xmlhttp.open("GET", "UpdateConsent.aspx?mb=" + MBID + " &ci= " + ConsentID + "&cd=" + ConsentDate +
                 "&wd=" + WithdrawDate + "&cw=" + ConsentWithdraw + "&ncn=" + NewConsentName + "&si=" + SampleID, false);

             xmlhttp.send(null);
         }
```

C#

```
  string lbSampleID = Request.QueryString["si"].ToString();
 using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"Update Sample
         set ConsentConfirmed='NO' , DateConsent='', ConsentNameID=@NewConsentName

            WHERE  MBID = @MBID and ConsentNameID = @ConsentID and SampleID=@SampleID", con))
                {
                    sc.Parameters.Add("@MBID", SqlDbType.Int).Value=MBID;

                    sc.Parameters.Add("@ConsentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ConsentID;
                    sc.Parameters.Add("@NewConsentName", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NewConsentName;

                    int records = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    int value = records;


                    int ListBox1 = Convert.ToInt32(lbSampleID);
            // Error with the loop
                  foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
                    {
                        if (item.Selected)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                sc.Parameters["@SampleID"].Value = item.Text;
                                sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }

                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                // Label1.Text = ex.Message;
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: For future reference, please see this article on creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the problem you are facing. Much of the code you have posted isn't pertinent to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right above the line that causes the error, you define `ListBox1` as a variable of type `int`.

```
int ListBox1 = Convert.ToInt32(lbSampleID);
```

Thus, the compiler throws an error, telling you that integers don't have any property called `Items`.

```
foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
{
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's this:

```
int ListBox1 = Convert.ToInt32(lbSampleID);
            // Error with the loop
                  foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
```

You've declared an `int` called `ListBox1` and assigned it a value. I think what you're trying to do is more like this:

```
             int i = Convert.ToInt32(lbSampleID);
 //if lbSampleID is a label, use its .Text Property   
               foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
                  if(item.ToString() == i.ToString())
                     {//do things }
```

But I can't really be sure what the logic is from the example posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some confusion created by your naming convention.
You got your ID from a querystring and named it "lbSampleID".
And now you are trying to find the ListBox control with the ID you obtain and declaring it as an int then running a foreach loop looking for the items.

I suggest renaming your ListBox as "lbSample", the ID as "sampleID".
Then you can get your intentions clearer.

I assume you meant something like:

```
//Here is the ListBox Control
 <asp:ListBox ID="lbSample" runat="server" Height="99px" Width="131px">   </asp:ListBox>
```

C#

```
//Here is the ID of the item you want update
string sampleID = Request.QueryString["si"].ToString();
using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"Update Sample
     set ConsentConfirmed='NO' , DateConsent='',  ConsentNameID=@NewConsentName

        WHERE  MBID = @MBID and ConsentNameID = @ConsentID and SampleID=@SampleID", con))
            {
                sc.Parameters.Add("@MBID", SqlDbType.Int).Value=MBID;

                sc.Parameters.Add("@ConsentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ConsentID;
                sc.Parameters.Add("@NewConsentName", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NewConsentName;

                int records = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                int value = records;
        //lbSample is the ListBox Control containing the items
              foreach (ListItem item in lbSample.Items)
                {
                     //here is looking for each item that hold same value as your same ID.
                    if (item.SelectedValue == sampleID)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            sc.Parameters["@SampleID"].Value = item.Text;
                            sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            // Label1.Text = ex.Message;
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
```